# move div smoothly with javascript/jquery and an array of pos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, game-physics

I'm looking for a way to move a div from an array of position with javascript/jquery.

I have trying to do it with jquery.animate but he moved the div with a pause at each iteration of my array.

That could be something like move the div from 0,0 to 120px,230px passing by the 23px,35px;45px,50px etc...

That is for moving an game character on a Tile map

So as requested, some bit of code

First you have a global timer that call a function at short interval to see if it have any action to execute.
In this loop a routine look if some mobile tiles are waiting of any mouvement.
Mobiles are declared as Object class and have a sub function that do the deplacement like that

```
setPos:function(coord){
    var pos = jQuery("#"+this.id).position();
    var x = (coord[0] - 32 + this.screenOffX + this.xOffset) - pos.left;
    var y =(coord[1] + this.yOffset) - pos.top;
    //this.stopAnimation();
    //this.startAnimation(this.walkingAnimation);
    jQuery("#"+this.id).animate({
        left: '+='+ x,
        top: '+='+ y
        }, 33, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
},
```

That is a bit messy cause i trying a lot of thing to do the smooth movement that i'm looking for.

so setPos is calling in another place like that

```
stepMobile:function(mobile){
    var wp;/*TEST*/
    mobile.changeState("idle");
    var ind = mobile.getWayPointIndex();
    while(ind < (mobile.getWayPoints()).length - 1){
        if (ind < (mobile.getWayPoints()).length - 1) {
            wp = (mobile.getWayPoints())[ind + 1];
            if (getTime() > wp.time) {
                mobile.setWayPointIndex(ind + 1);
                ind = ind +1;
            }
        }
        wp = (mobile.getWayPoints())[ind];  
        var x;
        var y = 0;
        var z;
        x = this.tileWidth * (wp.getTile()).getCol();
        z = this.tileHeight * (wp.getTile()).getRow();
        var elapsed = getTime() - wp.getTime();
        console.log(elapsed);
        if (ind == (mobile.getWayPoints()).length - 1) {
            console.log('checkForOnStopEvent()');
        } else {
            //x += 1 * mobile.getWalkSpeed() * mobile.getCosAngle();
            //z += 1 * mobile.getWalkSpeed() * mobile.getSinAngle();
        }
        var coord = this.mapToScreen(x, y, -z);
        mobile.setPos(coord);
        ind = mobile.getWayPointIndex();
    }
},
```

Again lot of junk code here cause i literally burned my brain but i didn't get any good result.

And you have that global function that run this function over all mobiles waiting for deplacement.

Comment: How does your game update/render?  Do you use the typical Update(dt)/Render(dt) gameloop?  If so, you'd want to control the animation in those (the position of the thing you want to move).  If not, what does your .animate() look like?  Include a little code please.

Comment: Source added to original post